# how to prove that $x_1+x_2<3e^{a-1} -1$

Tags: calculus

If $$f(x)=a-\frac{1}{x}-\ln x$$ where $a$ is a constant.   I want to prove$$x_1+x_2<3e^{a-1} -1$$when $f(x)$ just has two different zeros denoted by $x_1,x_2$.

Please could you help with this question?

Comment: Is $x_1,x_2$ are such that $f(x_1)=0, f(x_2)=0$?

Comment: at the moment I've found that $x_1+x_2\le 2e^a$

Comment: @Masacroso. How did you get this result ?

Comment: @Claude I assumed that $f$ is real valued, then $x_1,x_2>0$, otherwise $\ln x$ is not real. Then if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ then we can write $$x_1+x_2=e^{a-1/x_1}+e^{a-1/x_2}=e^a(e^{-1/x_1}+e^{-1/x_2})< 2e^a$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $x\in(0,1]$ and strictly decreasing in $x\in(1,\infty)$ and that $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ when $x\rightarrow 0^+$ and $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$.

$f$ has a maximum at $x=1$, since $f'(1)=0$ and $f(1)=a-1$.

For $a\leq 1$ there is less than two zeroes so $x_1+x_2$ is not defined.

For $a> 1$ we know (by Bolzano-Weierstrass) that $x_1< 1$, since $f(1)>0$ and $x_2< e^{a}$, since $f(e^{a})=-e^{-a}<0$.

Therefore, $x_1+x_2<1+e^{a}<3e^{a-1}-1$, when $a>2.959..$.

I let the case $1<a\leq2.959...$ for you to solve.

Comment: Would you give me some hints?